# wireless connection and nic card aren't recognized and doesn't come back until I reboot even if I restart network manager

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

My wireless connection completely disappears and isn't recognized along with my NIC card and doesn't come back until I reboot even if I restart network manager.

Steps:

```
1) I boot up type in sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off (turn off power management)

2) 
$ iwconfig
enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"2.4ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:29:93:3F:20   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:55   Missed beacon:0

3) I loose wifi using 5ghz or 2.4ghz after a certain amount of time

4) sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlmvm iwlwifi
5) sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

I do a **iwconfig** and **I'm missing wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"2.4ghz"**

```
$ iwconfig
enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have to reboot to get my wifi back how can I prevent this.

```
$ uname -a
Linux sys76 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
876.891600] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  876.891602] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[  877.909370] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  877.909397] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  877.909409] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[  878.928277] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  878.928364] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  878.928366] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[  879.947120] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  879.947170] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  879.947172] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5


$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for rt: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:2e:64:8e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: enp4s0f2
       version: 0a
       serial: 00:90:f5:f9:d4:f8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
$ 

ethtool -i wlp3s0 | grep driver
driver: iwlwifi

$ lsmod | grep r81 (when the wifi on my laptop is working)
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169

$ lsmod | grep r81 (when the wifi on my laptop goes down and NIC card isn't found)
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

Comment: For your NIC can you include the output of `lsmod | grep r81` both after boot and when interfaces dissapear. Also what happens after resuming from suspend?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I posted the output you requested.  If I resume suspend I reconnect but the icon changes from a wifi icon to arrows like I'm connected to an ethernet network and I loose the ability to choose / change to another wifi network because none of the wifi access points show up.

Comment: check this out: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359202